# Simple question about matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

My question is simple :
If one replaces some of the entries of a matrix by 0, does he obtain necessarily a matrix with a lower norm?
I have to precise that the norm I use is the maximum of the singular values of the matrix (which is an operator norm).

Answer (score 3):

Not true for the spectral norm you use. Simple example:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix},
\quad
\tilde{A} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{2}\approx 1.4142, \qquad 
\|\tilde{A}\|_2 = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{2}}\approx 1.6180.
$$
On the other hand, zeroing out entries of $A$ to get $\tilde{A}$ can give:

- strict inequality for the Frobenius norm (2-norm of the vector of the singular values): $\|\tilde{A}\|_F < \|A\|_F$,
- non-strict inequalities for some other norms, e.g.: $\|\tilde{A}\|_{\star} \leq \|A\|_{\star}$, where $\star = 1,\infty$ (usual matrix $p$-norms) or $\star=M$, where $\|A\|_M=\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$.